# Want to use href inside php variable

Tags: php, html, email

I need to send a verification email, its working fine. But i don want to show the "link" in the email i just need to show some text like "click here to verify"

```
{
$verify_email="
Hello,
Thank you for signup.
For verify e-mail go to this http://".$site_url."/verify.php?user=%s&key=%s;
Or enter your verify code on verification page. Code is: %s
Thanks you.
";
}
```

This sends a email like the below

Hello,
Thank you for signup.
For verify e-mail go to this http://testsite.com/verify.php?user=username&key=de94569d40077060f5f5eb;

But i need this to be

Hello,
Thank you for signup.
For verify e-mail *click here*

Please help me

Comment: You need to send mail as html. Then just use standard HTML markup. Knowing/learning HTML would have helped you resolve this on your own.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would this question get a down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
<?php
$to  = 'your recipients';
$subject = 'Your subject';
$message = 'Your html code';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: HTML formatted email without a plain text part is much more likely to be flagged as spam. Don't do that.

Comment: @Quentin what headers to use to prevent it then?

Comment: @Ivotje50 — See [the highest voted answer of the duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1162129/19068).

Comment: @Quentin your msg too helped me thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
{
$verify_email="
Hello,
Thank you for signup.
For verify e-mail <a href='http://".$site_url."/verify.php?user=%s&key=%s> go to this </a>
Or enter your verify code on verification page. Code is: %s
Thanks you.
";
}
```

This is regular HTML markup.  Use the anchor tag and enclose your URL in the href attribute.

Comment: You can't just stick HTML into a plain text email and expect it to be rendered as HTML.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for signup.
For verify e-mail <a href='http://testsite.com/verify.php?user=username&key=521fa47b83bb> go to this </a>
Or enter your verify code on verification page. Code is: 521fa47b83bb
Thanks you.   This is the mail i am getting for ur code

Comment: @Quentin I did not think that was what he was asking.  I only completed the string for him.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$verify_email='
Hello,
Thank you for signup.
For verify e-mail go to this <a href="http://'.$site_url.'/verify.php?user=%s&key=%s">Click here</a>
Or enter your verify code on verification page. Code is: %s Thanks you.';
```

Comment: You can't just stick HTML into a plain text email and expect it to be rendered as HTML.

Comment: then wat is the solution?

Comment: Yes. I know. I regularly use PHP mailers. But his problem is not rendering HTML code with mail. Atleast he didn't mention that. He was troubling with single quots and double quotes

Comment: @Quentin, ok sorry. I didn't understand the complete problem. 
so, Praveen why don't you go for PHP mailer?

Comment: @praveenrsmart — See [the highest voted answer of the duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1162129/19068).